# PHP - How can I write data from a <table></table> to an excel file using file_put_contents()?

Tags: php, excel, file-put-contents

PHP - How can I write data from a `<table></table>` to an excel file using `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: Please don't copy paste the question title in the details and that too twice. Write a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

save the spreadsheet as a CSV, then use PHP's built-in CSV functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

or use external libraries:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/